# Python: Pandas: making a dictionary from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am trying to convert a dataframe to dictionary:

```
xtest_cat = xtest_cat.T.to_dict().values()
```

but it gives a warning :

> Warning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted python

I checked the columns names of the dataframe(xtest_cat) :

```
len(list(xtest_cat.columns.values)) 
len(set(list(xtest_cat.columns.values)))
```

they are all unique.
Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: You called transpose so is your index unique? `xtest_cat.T` returns the transpose so the index become the columns

Comment: @EdChum. Yes I also checked that by the following :                                      `print len(xtrain_test.ix[:,0])
    print len(list(xtrain_test.ix[:,0]))
    print len(set(list(xtrain_test.ix[:,0])))`

Comment: You need check uniqueness of index by `print (xtest_cat.index.is_unique)`

Comment: @jezrael I checked by the following  `print len(xtrain_test.ix[:,0])
    print len(list(xtrain_test.ix[:,0]))
    print len(set(list(xtrain_test.ix[:,0])))` . Is it the same thing?

Comment: Not, because it test first column, not index.

Comment: @ZohairZahid also - if you're transposing before using `to_dict` it's generally a sign you should instead be looking at the `orient=` argument for `to_dict`...

Comment: @jezrael. I will try that but I wonder why will there be duplicate indexes. i am reading csv file through panda, which is xtrain_test. and then making a dictionary

Comment: @ZohairZahid - do you use only `read_csv` ? What is `xtrain_test.index` ?

Comment: @jezrael. Yes I am using read_csv, so should not the indexes be generated automatically ?

Comment: @ZohairZahid - it depends of data - sometimes yes, sometimes not.

Comment: @ZohairZahid - but if need force do not use index, add parameter `index_col=False` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for create `unique` index:

```
xtest_cat = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                          'B':[4,5,6],
                          'C':[7,8,9]})

xtest_cat.index = [0,1,1]
print (xtest_cat)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
1  3  6  9

print (xtest_cat.index.is_unique)
False

xtest_cat.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print (xtest_cat)
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

xtest_cat = xtest_cat.T.to_dict().values()
print (xtest_cat)
dict_values([{'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'A': 1}, {'B': 5, 'C': 8, 'A': 2}, {'B': 6, 'C': 9, 'A': 3}])
```

You can also omit `T` and add parameter `orient='index'`:

```
xtest_cat = xtest_cat.to_dict(orient='index').values()
print (xtest_cat)
dict_values([{'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'A': 1}, {'B': 5, 'C': 8, 'A': 2}, {'B': 6, 'C': 9, 'A': 3}])
```

`orient='record'` is better:

```
xtest_cat = xtest_cat.to_dict(orient='records')
print (xtest_cat)
[{'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'A': 1}, {'B': 5, 'C': 8, 'A': 2}, {'B': 6, 'C': 9, 'A': 3}]
```

Comment: How about  `xtest_cat = xtest_cat.to_dict('records')` ?

Comment: Yes, it is better.